# RecyclerView Animation On Activity Exit

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, android-recyclerview

I am making an app that includes recyclerview. The items of recyclerview show up (slide in) with animation from the bottom on activity start. when clicking an item, it navigates to another activity. I want the items to disappear (slide out) with animation before exiting current activity. In my case I want items to drop down (slide out) and then new activity starts. is there any way to sliding out items before exiting activity?

**EDIT:** something like below:
[image]

Comment: Are you using ContentTransition ?

Comment: @RohitSingh no, I did not use ContentTransition. I want to know how can I remove recyclerview's item (not deleting!!!).

Comment: You should attach a sample Gif to explain your question clearly. I have done some similar Animation but I dont know what exactly do you want.

Comment: with compose might be more easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**LayoutAnimationController:**

Using the build in [LayoutAnimationController](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/LayoutAnimationController) you can achieve the slide out effect using a custom animation slide from top to bottom with animation order to be the `LayoutAnimationController.ORDER_REVERSE` to start the animation from the bottom right child item view.

1.)Declare in your `res/anim/slide_from_top_to_bottom.xml` the slide out animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="250">

    <translate
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="100%p"/>

    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="1"
        android:toAlpha="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>

</set>
```

2.)Use the below helper to start the above animation by setting the `LayoutAnimationController` into the `RecyclerView` using the `setLayoutAnimation()` method:

```
private void slideOutRecyclerViewLayoutAnimation(final RecyclerView recyclerView)
{
    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_from_top_to_bottom);
    animation.setFillAfter(true); //true if the animation should apply its transformation after it ends
    LayoutAnimationController lac = new LayoutAnimationController(animation);
    lac.setOrder(LayoutAnimationController.ORDER_REVERSE);
    lac.setDelay(0.15f);

    recyclerView.setLayoutAnimation(lac);
    recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
    recyclerView.scheduleLayoutAnimation();

    //go to the next Activity after 1sec
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //go to the next Activity
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

**Custom ItemAnimator:**

In case you want to have more customisation in the animation delay of each child with a different slide out order something like in your gif you can use a custom `SimpleItemAnimator` and use the `public boolean animateRemove(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder)` which is called when an item in the RecyclerView has been removed. It called when you remove only one item like `notifyItemRemoved()` or when you remove a range of items like `notifyItemRangeRemoved()`.

1.)Create the `CustomAnimator` like the below sample:

```
public class CustomAnimator extends SimpleItemAnimator {

    private final int columns;
    private final int rows;

    public CustomAnimator(int columns, int itemsCount){
        this.columns = columns;
        this.rows = (int) Math.ceil((double) itemsCount / (double)columns);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean animateRemove(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {

        //to get the item view position set in RecyclerView.Adapter#onBindViewHolder the position to the item view like: itemView.setTag(position);
        int position = (int)holder.itemView.getTag();

        int x = position % columns;
        int y = position / columns;

        int yDiff = rows - y;
        long delay = 0;
        switch (x)
        {
            //column 0
            case 0:
                delay = yDiff * 60L;
                break;
            //column 1
            case 1:
                delay = yDiff * 50L;
                break;
            //column 2
            case 2:
                delay = yDiff * 40L;
                break;
            //column 3
            case 3:
                delay = yDiff * 30L;
                break;
        }

        int height = holder.itemView.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
        holder.itemView.setTranslationY(0);
        holder.itemView.setAlpha(1);
        holder.itemView.animate()
                .translationY(height)
                .alpha(0)
                .setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator())
                .setDuration(500)
                .setStartDelay(delay)
                .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                        dispatchRemoveFinished(holder);
                    }
                })
                .start();
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean animateAdd(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean animateMove(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int fromX, int fromY, int toX, int toY) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean animateChange(RecyclerView.ViewHolder oldHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder newHolder, int fromLeft, int fromTop, int toLeft, int toTop) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void runPendingAnimations() {

    }

    @Override
    public void endAnimation(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder item) {

    }

    @Override
    public void endAnimations() {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isRunning() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

2.)In your `RecyclerView.Adapter` in `onBindViewHolder` set the position of each item into the tag to be retrieved later from the `CustomAnimator` like below:

```
itemView.setTag(position);
```

3.)During the `RecyclerView` initialisation set the `ItemAnimator` like below:

```
//set GridLayoutManager with 4 columns
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 4));
//prepare some dummy items
List<Item> itemsList = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i =0; i<26; i++) {
    itemsList.add(new Item());
}
//initialize Adapter
itemsAdapter = new MyAdapter(itemsList);
//set recyclerView Adapter
recyclerView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
//set recyclerView CustomAnimator
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new CustomAnimator(4, itemsAdapter.getItems().size()));
```

4.)Finally when you click on an item call the below helper to start the animation:

```
private void removeAllItems(){

    int itemsCount = itemsAdapter.getItems().size();
    itemsAdapter.getItems().clear();
    recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, itemsCount);

    //go to the next Activity after 1sec
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //go to the next Activity after 1sec
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

**Result:**

[image: anim3]

Answer (score 2):

### You need the [Slide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzWMq.gif) Animation.

I have used it in one of my Android app. I will explain this with Explode Animation.

Lets say you have 2 activities A(GridList Activity) and B(DetailActivity).
**A-->B**

[image]

You can achieve this in these simple steps

**1. Enable Content Transition**

Add this code in your `style.xml`

```
<item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
```

**2. Set Default enter and exit Animation**

Write this method in Activity A which will handle animation for you.

```
public void setAnimation()
{
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>20) {
        Explode explode = new Explode();
        explode.setDuration(1000);
        explode.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        getWindow().setExitTransition(explode);
        getWindow().setEnterTransition(explode);
    }
}
```

**3. Start Activity with Intent**

Add this in your Activity A for starting Activity B. Note that the animation works only above `SDK>20`. So if your min sdk is lower then you will have to a check for SDK as well. Just use this code snippet and you will be good to go.

```
 public void startActivity(){

    Intent i = new Intent(BlankActivity.this, AllImageActivity.class);
    i.putStringArrayListExtra(MOVIE_LIST, movie.getImages());

      if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>20)
       {
           ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(BlankActivity.this);
           startActivity(i,options.toBundle());
       }
       else {
           startActivity(i);
       }
 }
```

### Very Important

You should place the `setAnimation()` before `setContentView(R.layout.yourLayout)` else the animation will not work. So the Activity A should look like this

```
Activity A extends .... {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstaceState)
   {
       super.onCreate(savedInstaceState);

       setAnimation();

       setContentView(R.layout.image_landing_layout);

       startActivity();  // Use as you wish 
       .......
   }

   public void setAnimation(){

       ..........
   }
```

I am not writing this on any IDE so don't mind any syntax errors. But this will push you in the right track.
You may checkout my [Repository](https://github.com/rohitksingh/Mangoose/blob/master/OMDB/app/src/main/java/com/omdb/rohksin/Mangoose/LandingActivities/AllImageActivity.java) . But you may have hard time finding it there. Hope this helps.

Comment: It was a nice animation, I liked it. But it was not my answer, your sample explodes activity (or other animation on activity). My intention is to slide all items and disapear them so I could hide the recyclerview!

Comment: You can use this method It is similar but not the exact Animation. I am going to add more sample Animation. 
 https://github.com/rohitksingh/Animation-Demo/blob/5a2a71c40e840ad0cd2062ba546c0ce31807c490/app/src/main/java/rohitksingh/com/androidanimationdemo/GridListActivity.java#L71 .